# What happened to the 98 applicants between episode 5 and 6?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

At the end of episode 5 the narrator states that 202 candidates have been eliminated from the previous round leaving 148 candidates left. When episode 6 starts they are entering to meet the Gourmet Hunters and Satotz states there are 50 candidates. Are we missing something from them walking through the gate?

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the examiner of the first phase is odd, but he was saying he thought 50 would pass and then corrected his statement to only 10 would pass.

There were still 148 applicants but he was stating 2 numbers of how many he thought would pass.

(also in ep5 the narrator stated 220, but I figured that was a typo)